# Counting lines in file ambiguity

Tags: python-2.6

I have this code to count each line in a file:

```
n = sum(1 for line in open('myfile.txt'))
```

'n' being the number of lines. But it's not giving the correct number of lines. There's a difference of hundreds in count. Also tried different ways found in google but nothings seems to do the trick.

Any idea why this is happening? Or are there scenarios that stop this from giving the correct count?

--UPDATE--

Tried re-writing the file to another file:

```
i = 0
with open(file2) as outFile:
   with open(file1) as inFile:
       for line in inFile:
           outFile.write(line)
           i += 1
```

The output is file2 is exactly the same as file1 when seen on a viewer in terms of number of lines. However the value of 'i' doesn't give the correct number of lines.

Comment: Are the line terminators in your file consistent?

Comment: How many lines are in the file, and how many do you get for `n`? Also, what OS, and how are the line terminators? Do you see anything odd if your print the `line`s, maybe two merged lines where there is one in the editor?

Comment: @tobias_k Total number of lines should be 27,109 but I'm only getting 26,694. Using Windows as OS. It has CR/LF and CR. There's nothing odd in the. Tried re-writing it to a new file and it has the exact number of lines.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes they are consistent

Comment: @albert, you said in a previous comment that your file *has CR/LF and CR*. That doesn't look very consistent to me.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The way CR/LF and CR are laid out are consistent. But yeah it has two different terminators

Comment: @albert, I think that's the cause of your problem. If you can convert all the terminators to CR+LF, I believe you will get the right line count.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would just be to open the file, and then count the number of lines in the file's `readlines()` method.

```
f = open('yourfile.txt', 'r')
print len(f.readlines())
```

Comment: This gives you the number of _characters_! EDIT: Now it will probably give exactly the same value as in OP's code (but in a less memory-efficient way)

Comment: Oops, you're right, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @tobias_k I checked the length of the file in a text editor, and it is consistent with the value I got, so it is indeed correct.

Comment: He did say his wasn't giving the correct number of lines, ans my answer addressed that problem, I don't know what else I could say.

Comment: Yes, but his code _should_ give the right number, too. Did you try his code on your own test file? Ergo, the problem is not with the code (or if it is, yours probably has the same problem) but rather with the file.

Comment: **Additional info**
Tried re-writing the whole file to another file while adding i += 1 in the loop to count each line. The output is the same as the first file but the count still doesn't match.

Comment: What is the real line count and what is the number you're getting?